# Inherited permissions lost while giving NTFS permissions

Tags: c#, permissions

I was trying to give NTFS permissions on a UNC path for a specific user, but I see different behavior depending on the UNC path. Below is the code (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1f66bc2.aspx)) which I am using to give permissions and the result in each scenario,

```
static void GiveNTFSPermissions(string folderPath, 
                                string ntAccountName, 
                                FileSystemRights accessRights)
{
    DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(folderPath);

    FileSystemAccessRule newAccessRule =
         new FileSystemAccessRule(
               ntAccountName,
               accessRights,
               AccessControlType.Allow);

    dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(newAccessRule);

    Directory.SetAccessControl(folderPath, dirSecurity);
}
```

Suppose I have a share named “*RootShare*” on my local machine, and another folder “*InsideRootShare*” inside it.

**Scenario1:**
When I call,

```
GiveNTFSPermissions(@"\\sri-devpc\RootShare",
                    @"domain\username",
                    FileSystemRights.Write);
```

**Inherited permissions were lost on the shared path,**

**Scenario2:**
When I call,

```
GiveNTFSPermissions(@"\\sri-devpc\RootShare\InsideRootShare", 
                    @"domain\username", 
                    FileSystemRights.Write);
```

**Inherited permissions were intact.**

I have tried with different constructors of `FileSystemAccessRule` but no luck.

**What is the reason behind this behavior, and any workaround for this?**

Comment: Did you try the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule.aspx) which takes `InheritanceFlags` as argument? Also, `AddNTFSPermission` is a more reasonable name than `GiveNTFSPermissions`, as it attempts to *add* a new access rule to the existing access rules.

Comment: See this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243995/setting-folder-permissions-on-vista

Comment: @Nawaz: I have tried all constructors, and I have the same result. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: What flags combinations did you use? Can you see the access rules before and after *SetAccessControl*? See if they differ by exactly one rule (which is just added)

Comment: @Nawaz: I have tried with InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,PropagationFlags.None. And I have checked in scenario2 it differs only by one. And in scenario1 I can see only the one which is added all the other are lost. The above code can be executed as is, if you want to try on you machine.

Answer (score 5):

We ran into similar issues working with file system permission while working on Dropkick's security module. The solution we came up with is as follows. This will successfully set permissions on any folder without changing the inheritance rules on the folder.

```
    public void SetFileSystemRights(string target, string group, FileSystemRights permission)
    {
        if (!IsDirectory(target) && !IsFile(target))
            return;

        var oldSecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(target);
        var newSecurity = new DirectorySecurity();

        newSecurity.SetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm(oldSecurity.GetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm());

        var accessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(group,
                                                  permission,
                                                  InheritanceFlags.None,
                                                  PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit,
                                                  AccessControlType.Allow);
        bool result;
        newSecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Set, accessRule, out result);

        if (!result) Log.AddError("Something wrong happened");

        accessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(group,
                                              permission,
                                              InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit |
                                              InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                                              PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,
                                              AccessControlType.Allow);

        result = false;
        newSecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Add, accessRule, out result);
        if (!result) Log.AddError("Something wrong happened");

        Directory.SetAccessControl(target, newSecurity);

        if (result) Log.AddGood("Permissions set for '{0}' on folder '{1}'", group, target);

        if (!result) Log.AddError("Something wrong happened");
    }
```

Found [the link that I originally used to figure this out](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/4072.aspx).