# Trying to secure a directory on windows using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to have my C# program secure a local existing directory on a windows machine. For security reasons, I only want accounts in the administrators group to have access to this folder. The existing folder is one that my program previously created and will be owned by the current running user, so I will need to both add privileges for the admin group and then remove privileges for the current user.

I am able to add the admin group's privileges to the folder, but I can't figure out how to remove the current user's permissions. I am giving the admin group permissions as follows:

```
DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = new DirectorySecurity();
IdentityReference adminId = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
FileSystemAccessRule adminAccess = new FileSystemAccessRule(
    adminId,
    FileSystemRights.FullControl,
    InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,
    PropagationFlags.None,
    AccessControlType.Allow);
directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(adminAccess);

// set the owner and the group to admins
directorySecurity.SetOwner(adminId);
directorySecurity.SetGroup(adminId);

Directory.SetAccessControl("path-to-my-directory", directorySecurity);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now see the real issue.  You were already effectively removing the other user's access by setting the directory security to a brand new object instead of getting the existing directory security and modifying it, but your directory was still getting the inherited permissions from the parent.

What you need on your new directory security object to remove the parent inheritance.  You can do this through the [SetAccessRuleProtection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection.aspx) method.  You can use your above code as is, but add this line before you set the access control on the directory.

```
directorySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the access rule that contains the access for the current user using one of the RemoveAccessRule* methods defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx).

Or you could add an access rule to deny access to the current user, but I always try to stay away from deny rules.  It is usually better to not grant access than to deny access (unless it is really intended to fully deny access like in financial records or other sensitive information).  FYI, deny access rules will override ALL grant accesses rules.

Comment: I think this is close to what I need... using the code samples in the link you provided I still can't remove the current user though. However, I think this is because the directory is inheriting permissions from its parent. Would you happen to know how to disable this programatically?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354481/inherited-permissions-lost-while-giving-ntfs-permissions). It explains the code you have to write to modify file system permissions. If you do not do all of the steps listed, you will not be able to successfully modify the permissions on the file system.